# QuickBooks 2019 Desktop Accountant Silent Install

Tags: quickbooks

We've been trying to deploy QuickBooks 2019 through SCCM for a while now (using a transform file since Intuit refuses to implement any sort of command line switches for whatever reason). The normal method for deployment using applications or packages hasn't worked. I'm using msiexec in a batch file to run the install, but it doesn't seem to work with "/qb" specified. If I remove the "/qb", the command runs and the install works just fine, but that obviously eliminates the silent part, which is the whole point of attempting this. Any advice on what else to try to get this working is appreciated. Here's the command as it is right now:

msiexec /i "%~dp0QBooks\QuickBooks.msi" TRANSFORMS="%~dp0QBooks.mst" /qb

Answer (score 0):

Try the /qn instead of the /qb.
Would be willing to share your transform file or share what needs to be changed on the transform file?